# Cannot use 'HSET' with redis-cluster

Tags: codeigniter, redis, redis-cluster, predis

**Query:**

I am using a Redis cluster. Trying to use hset store user data.
I am not able to figure out why this error is coming.

**Env:**

```
Library: Predis-1.0.3
redis: 3.0.6
php: 5.4
Framework : codeigniter(2.1.0)
```

**ERROR:**

```
Predis\NotSupportedException: Uncaught exception 'Predis\NotSupportedException' with message 'Cannot use 'HSET' with redis-cluster.' in /var/www/domain.name/application/libraries/predis-1.0/src/Connection/Aggregate/RedisCluster.php:299
in Predis\Connection\Aggregate\RedisCluster::getConnection called at /var/www/domain.name/application/libraries/predis-1.0/src/Connection/Aggregate/RedisCluster.php (470)
in Predis\Connection\Aggregate\RedisCluster::executeCommand called at /var/www/domain.name/application/libraries/predis-1.0/src/Client.php (326)
in Predis\Client::executeCommand called at /var/www/domain.name/application/libraries/predis-1.0/src/Client.php (310)
in Predis\Client::__call called at /var/www/domain.name/application/libraries/REST_Controller.php (937)
in Predis\Client::hset called at /var/www/domain.name/application/libraries/REST_Controller.php (937)
```

Comment: it is not specific to `hset` command, you may also not use some of other commands too. You need to re-configure your cluster configuration, please check https://github.com/nrk/predis/issues/562

Comment: @Ersoy I have followed the predis documentation for [configuration](https://github.com/nrk/predis).
This my config 
`$parameters = ['tcp://10.0.0.1', 'tcp://10.0.0.2', 'tcp://10.0.0.3'];
$options    = ['cluster' => 'redis'];
$client = new Predis\Client($parameters, $options);`

Comment: This error is not coming every time. its kind of random I am not able find the pattern when this error shows.
Maybe when the traffic is high this error is coming.

Comment: I checked the library, it looks like it is related to `ClusterStrategy`:`getSlot` - please check this document - https://redis.io/commands/cluster-slots